# Practical way of setting Canny edge detection algorithm parameters automatically

Tags: algorithm, opencv, edge-detection

Canny edge detector is often used in many image processing tasks. However, in order to obtain a descent edge detection map carefully setting its parameters is very important. Based on my experience there are three important parameters: one is the blurring level, which is performed before canny edge detection, and the other two are the low threshold and high threshold of Canny edge detector. So my question is: how can we set these parameters automatically?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.kerrywong.com/2009/05/07/canny-edge-detection-auto-thresholding/) you have an interesting article that tries to determine the thresholds automatically by equalizing the histogram of the image.